# JSF rendered method is not invoked in the second time

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I have next a4j:jsFunction

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="renderOnBusinessErrorEvent" execute="@none" bypassUpdates="true" immediate="true"
            render="securityForm">
        </a4j:jsFunction>
```

and JSF form with some dialog inside

```
<h:form id="securityForm">
      <h:panelGroup rendered="#{someCondition}">
      ......
      </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
```

In my business logic it has to be executed twice consequently. In the first time all is fine. Rendered method is invoked and the expected dialog is present on the page. In the second time rendered method is not invoked, but model has been changed and I expect that dialog will not be present on the page. I supposed that it's some richfaces issue and I tried to use f:ajax

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="renderOnBusinessErrorEvent" execute="@none" bypassUpdates="true" immediate="true">
            <f:ajax event="begin" render=":securityForm"/>
        </a4j:jsFunction>
```

but unsuccessfully. Rendered method still not invoked in the second time. What is it? Some JSF optimization or bug? What's the workaround?
JSF version 2.1.19

Comment: You did not show how and when are you calling that function. You should also check network activity, if there are two requests then the function was executed twice.

Comment: @Makhiel I'm calling this function just through javascript like renderOnBusinessErrorEvent(); with delay about 2 seconds.
Network activity is fine (200), but responses for the same request are different.

Comment: @Makhiel If I do not quite clearly described the details of the problem, just in case I will explain. This function was executed twice. I added console.log for debug. But response for the second call is differ from the first call. And I don't know why. If it's not correct behavior for JSF, I hope that is not the case, then I'll try to reproduce it on the small project and create new issue in JSF bug tracker.

Comment: You can try a4j:log, but put it outside of the form. Where do the responses differ? They have to be different if they're supposed to render different things.

Comment: With a4j:log I found the root of my problem. I've posted the message as separate answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `<h:panelGroup rendered="#{someOtherCondition}">` 
over h:form which equals false after the first rendering (ON THE SERVER SIDE).
However, this panelGroup is not part of rendering. So, my code:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{someOtherCondition}">
    <h:form id="securityForm">
          <h:panelGroup rendered="#{someCondition}">
          ......
          </h:panelGroup>
     </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:form>
    <a4j:jsFunction name="renderOnBusinessErrorEvent" execute="@none" bypassUpdates="true" immediate="true"
            render="securityForm">
    </a4j:jsFunction>
</h:form>
```

Before calling renderOnBusinessErrorEvent() I'm changing the value of someOtherCondition from true to false, but I don't rerender this element. Actually, on the server side this element is already missing. Looks like it's JSF feature, but is it specificated somewhere?

Comment: As you've seen JSF sends back pieces of HTML code, because the form's parent isn't rendered the form isn't rendered either, so no code is sent.

Comment: @Makhiel Exactly. But it's not obvious. When element is absent on the page, JSF should throw FacesException. But not Richfaces, I know. That is why I done the check with f:ajax